# using ivy completion on a hydra

Tags: ivy, hydra

I'd like to use ivy completion to select items from my hydra rather than using the specified keymap. The use case would be for a very large hydra. I could create nested hydras, but I want to be lazy and just keep adding stuff to one large hydra without spending time organizing or formatting it. Technically, a hydra isn't required for the solution. Could also just be a list of functions, preferably with hints, and a method to select them via ivy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting from hydra, I would start from counsel-M-x. This function uses `ivy-read`, which wants a list of possible inputs, and a function to run once you've chosen one. You can provide it a list of the commands you want to run, and use `counsel-M-x-action` as the function to run. Here's an example:

```lisp
(defvar my/commands '(shell scroll-down text-mode))

(defun my/commands ()
  (interactive)
  (ivy-read "Command: " my/commands
            :caller 'my-commands
            :require-match t
            :action #'counsel-M-x-action))
```

For customization, Ivy has "display transformers", which let you display something other than the command name. You could use this to add hints. First, add `:caller 'my-commands` to the ivy-read, so that this command has a name. Then, use `ivy-configure` to tell Ivy to use your function for displaying text:

```lisp
(defun my/commands-display (candidate)
  (format "%s - add hint here" candidate))
 
(ivy-configure 'my-commands
  :display-transformer-fn #'my/commands-display)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. Could you elaborate on ivy-set-display-transformer. Can't seem to figure out how to use it for this use case.

Comment: Sure, l'll edit the answer with an example of ivy-set-display-transformer, which seems to have recently changed its name to ivy-configure.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get it to display different hits for each candidate. This is what I tried, but not working.    
    '''
    
    (defun my/commands-display (candidate)
      (setq x
     '((scroll-down . "scroll down hint")
       (text-mode . "text mode hint")))
      (cdr(assoc candidate x)))
    
    (ivy-configure 'my-commands
      :display-transformer-fn #'my/commands-display)
'''

Comment: Looks like the display transformer receives the *string* that was going to be displayed, and needs to return another string. So if you change the symbols to strings it should work: `(defun my/commands-display (candidate) (let ((x '(("scroll-down" . "scroll down hint") ("text-mode" . "text mode hint")))) (cdr (assoc candidate x))))`